# C# Replace tab to linebreak in firebird database

Tags: c#

I want to get 4 lines below each other in the firebird database.

My C# code looks like:

```
Comments = "Line 1.\n\t\t\t\t  Line 2\n\t\t\t\t  Line 3\n\t\t\t\t  Line 4";
Comments.Replace("\n\t\t\t\t ", "||ASCII_CHAR(13)||ASCII_CHAR(10)||");
```

But that gives this result:

```
"Line 1.||ASCII_CHAR(13)||ASCII_CHAR(10)|| Line 2||ASCII_CHAR(13)||ASCII_CHAR(10)|| Line 3||ASCII_CHAR(13)||ASCII_CHAR(10)|| Line 4"
```

How should this be done properly to have 4 separate lines, instead of 1 concatenated line with the unwanted tags in it?

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable.

`.Replace()` returns a new, modified, string, which you are ignoring.